# View not drawing when using singleton pattern

Tags: ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, singleton

Am drawing a UIView in a navigationController and I need to see that view even if the user push the back button, so I make the method that create the View in the AppDelegate to share it between the app.

When I use `(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` and then use the method that create the View like `[appDelegate createBottomView];` I can see the view, but obviously If the user go back and then forward, the AppDelegate will instance it again, and the values of the view will be null again.
So I made a singleton to create the AppDelegate in my classes:

```
AppDelehate.m
+(id)sharedInstance
{
static dispatch_once_t pred;
static AppDelegate *sharedInstance = nil;
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"DISPATCHED");
});
return sharedInstance;
}
```

And I call it in my classes like `AppDelegate appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];`

BUT, if I call the method `[appDelegate createBottomView];` the view is not drawn in my navController.

Why the view is not been drawn when I use the singleton pattern?
How should I do it?

Comment: Your 'sharedInstance' looks fine, but what are you doing in 'createBottomView'?

Answer (score 0):

- Make the View as a property in your AppDelegate
- Create the View in the `didFinishLaunching` in your AppDelegate Class
- Add the View to the viewcontrollers View whenever you want to show the view.